# Perl to Python Conversion issues: Regex interpretation

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying to convert some code from Perl to Python. I'm having issues in understanding regular expression used in Perl since I never learned Perl before.

Can anyone please help me understand the below line of code?

```
$seqfile =~ /(\S+)\.txt/
```

**********New Question:**************

Below, the variable 'name' has string value associated with it. How come the following line updates(use of ++) the value of hash variable(hash_lib) as if it's an integer value.
if it's a hash why doesn't it use a '%' when declaring hash variable. Can you create a hash with '$'?

```
 $hash_lib{$name}++;
```

Another thing is, can we create hash with two keys for a single value? if so, what would be python equivalent of the following line?

```
 $hash_abun{$name}{$seq}= $abun;
```

Comment: This will store any non-whitespace characters that come before `/.txt/` (the dot here is a regex dot -- any character) into the variable `$1`

Comment: The backslash was not visible before the question was edited. It means it is not a wildcard, but matches a literal period `.`. The whole regex looks like an attempt to capture the basename of a filename, with the extension `txt`.

Comment: A quick question: I have the following line of code in the while loop using the next operator. Does the below line mean "skip any line that has "abundance" written in them"?                                                                                                                              next if ($_ =~ m/abundance/i);

Comment: @parthpatel Yes, it does.

Comment: @parth Note the `i` flag at the end of `m/abundance/i`. That means to do a case-insensitive match, so it will also match `Abundance`, `ABUNDANCE`, and `AbUnDaNcE`.

Comment: Thank you @ TLP and ThisSuitlsBlackNot

Comment: I posted a new question under previous question. Please help me in this Perl to python transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(\S+)\.txt/
#     ^^^^^--- file extension?
# ^^^--------- file name?
```

The regex will match a string of one or more non-whitespace characters `\S+` -- probably a file name -- followed by the literal string `.txt` -- probably a file extension. This file name is captured into the variable `$1` (and also returned by the expression, if in list context). Typically this expression should be used like below to capture the string:

```
my $basename;
...
if ($seqfile =~ /(\S+)\.txt/) {
    $basename = $1;
}
```

Or

```
my ($basename) = $seqfile =~ /(\S+)\.txt/
```

This is likely a way to capture the basename of a plain text file. A better way to do such a thing would be to use `File::Basename qw(basename)`. But that might be irrelevant for Perl to Python conversion.

Answer (score 0):

`\S`===non space characters

`+`====1 or more

``` (``) ```===group1

`.`=====any character

`txt`===txt

Comment: I think an important "Perl-specific" note about that line of code is the fact that the matching group gets stored in `$1`